# jQuery AJAX function not running properly in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

```
function createLead(values) {
    var url = "/api/v1/createlead/?apikey=XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX";
    //debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        url : url,
        data : values,
        success: function (result) {
            result = $.parseJSON(result);
            if (result.redirect) {

                $(window).trigger('googleEvent' , 'regFailure');
                window.location.href = values.returnUrl;
                return;
            }
            else if (result.status === "OK" ) {

                if (result.data.isPixelToBeFired){
                    $(window).trigger('googleEvent' , 'pixelFire'); 
                }
                else {
                    $(window).trigger('googleEvent', 'noPixelFire');
                }

                olp_sLeadId = result.data.leadId;
                olp_sPathId = result.data.pathId;
                $(window).trigger('googleEvent', 'regSuccess');
                window.location = "path.html?curPathId=" + olp_sPathId
                        + "&curLeadId=" + olp_sLeadId; // Enter the path
            } 

            else {
                // console.log('FAIL' , result , values);
                $(window).trigger('googleEvent' , 'regFailue');
                window.location.href = values.returnUrl;
                return;
            }
        },
        statusCode: {
            404: function() {
                $(window).trigger('googleEvent' , 'createLead404');
                window.location.href = values.returnUrl;
                //console.log('Something is seriously wrong');
                return false;
            }
        },
        failure: function (result) {
            $(window).trigger('googleEvent' , 'createLeadFailure');
            window.location.href = values.returnUrl;
            //console.log('Something is seriously wrong');
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I've been scratching my head here for a while, all version of IE seem to have an issue with this call. A few important pieces of information here:

1. values is a data object and I can verify that it has data.
2. All window .trigger functions are for Google analytics tracking, they are used in several other parts of the code and do not present an issue.
3. In IE the function seems to be spaced oddly, all the other functions line up properly, but this one seems to be aligned oddly, making me wonder if something isn't parsing right?
4. The success function appears to not run, and the failure and statusCode functions are completely ignored. This leads me to wonder if this isn't an issue with the jQuery methods, but they function elsewhere in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is an issue with cache. The IE automatically cached the ajax request. To overcome this problem set option `cache: false` in you $.ajax code.

**Example :**

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    url : url,
    data : values,
    cache : false,
    // existing stuff
});
```

Hope this will help !!